# How to move rows in sections?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I try to move rows in sections, but get error:

> Fatal error: Index out of range

How I can implement this functionality for moving rows in sections and make this work correct? My full code:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

var mobileBrand = [MobileBrand]()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButtonItem

    mobileBrand.append(MobileBrand.init(brandName: "Apple", modelName: ["iPhone 5s","iPhone 6","iPhone 6s", "iPhone 7+", "iPhone 8", "iPhone 8+", "iPhone 11", "iPhone 11 Pro"]))
    mobileBrand.append(MobileBrand.init(brandName: "Samsung", modelName: ["Samsung M Series", "Samsung Galaxy Note 9", "Samsung Galaxy Note 9+", "Samsung Galaxy Note 10", "Samsung Galaxy Note 10 +"]))
    mobileBrand.append(MobileBrand.init(brandName: "Mi", modelName: ["Mi Note 7", "Mi Note 7 Pro", "Mi K20"]))
    mobileBrand.append(MobileBrand.init(brandName: "Huawei", modelName: ["Huawei Mate 20", "Huawei P30 Pro", "Huawei P10 Plus", "Huawei P20"]))
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return mobileBrand.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return mobileBrand[section].modelName?.count ?? 0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = mobileBrand[indexPath.section].modelName?[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return mobileBrand[section].brandName
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
  let movedObject = mobileBrand[sourceIndexPath.row]
  mobileBrand.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
  mobileBrand.insert(movedObject, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove from the nested array not the main as you move a row not a whole section

```
let movedObject = mobileBrand[sourceIndexPath.section].modelName?[sourceIndexPath.row]  
mobileBrand[sourceIndexPath.section].modelName?.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
mobileBrand[destinationIndexPath.section].modelName?.insert(movedObject, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
```

make sure `modelName` is mutable ( declared as var )